# how to use join for three tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have 3 tables. I want to fetch the employee details for those employees  only in table3. But when i ran the query i am getting all the employees names from table1

Table1 and table 2 has many employees.

Table3 has only one employee name.

Is the below query is correct? need some advise !!

i am using left join because i want mis-match records also from table1

```
select emp.emp_name, emp.dept, sal.salary 
from table1 as emp 
   left join table2 as sal on emp.emp_name = sal.emp_name 
                          and emp.emp_name in (select emp_name from table3)
```

Comment: try "where emp.emp_name in (select emp_name from table3)" instead of "and emp.emp_name in..etc"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is not correct, given what you want it to do, as the `and emp.emp_name in ...` part is part of the `left join` condition and won't limit the rows in `table1`. This is why you get all rows from `table1`.

To get all rows in `table1` that have matches in `table3`, plus the salary stuff (or null if missing) from `table2` you can either change the second part of the `left join` condition to a where clause or use an `inner join` with `table3`:

```
-- using a where clause
select emp.emp_name, emp.dept, sal.salary 
from table1 as emp 
left join table2 as sal on emp.emp_name = sal.emp_name 
where emp.emp_name in (select emp_name from table3);

-- or an inner join
select emp.emp_name, emp.dept, sal.salary 
from table1 as emp 
join table3 as t3 on emp.emp_name = t3.emp_name
left join table2 as sal on emp.emp_name = sal.emp_name;
```

For example if your tables had the following data:

```
table1: emp1, emp2, emp3
table2: emp1, emp2
table3: emp1, emp3
```

you would get:

```
emp_name   salary
emp1       1000
emp3       NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Do Inner Join to get correct result

```
 select 
   emp.emp_name, 
   emp.dept, 
   sal.salary 
 from table1 as emp 
   inner join table2 as sal on emp.emp_name = sal.emp_name and 
                               emp.emp_name in (select emp_name from table3)
```

Comment: Read the last line in the question again.